# Rails merge two query results and then query again

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Suppose, I have two query like

```
users = User.where("name =?", 'john')
active_johns = users.where("active =?", true)
```

Now I have to combine the results of the two query and then perform another query on result as below

```
users = users + active_johns
users = users.where("role = ?", 'admin')
```

This does not work and I get error

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `where' )
```

So how can I combine both results and then perform another where query on the result?

**Edit**

I really need to add the results of two queries. My situation is a bit complicated and I can not use single query for the two queries

```
users = User.where("name =?", 'john')
active_johns = users.where("active =?", true)
```

Then I need to add the results of the two query and then query again.

Comment: It seems you want to do `User.where(name: 'john', active: true, role: 'admin')`?

Comment: You can do all that thing in a single query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
User.where("name =?", 'john').where("active =?", true).where("role = ?", 'admin')
```

Or if you really need the results of two queries and only then the final result:

```
users = User.where("name =?", 'john').where("active =?", true)
admin_users = users.where("role = ?", 'admin')
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this out

`users = User.where("name =?", 'john')
 active_johns = users.where("active =?", true)
 users.merge(active_johns)`

Answer (score 0):

When you do the following:

```
users = users + active_johns
```

The result is an `Array`, not an `ActiveRecord::Association`. You cannot perform a `where` query on an `Array`. This is why you get

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `where' )
```

As @baxang suggested in his comment, you should use the following query to get what you desire:

```
User.where(name: 'John', active: true, role: 'admin')
```

This should give you all the active admin users named 'John'. I feel this is the best option without more details as to why you need to run 2 queries.